# How to run resque after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, resque

I am attempting the following.

```
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :book

    after_save { Resque.enqueue(EPubMaker, self.book.id) }
end
```

What this should do is run the 'perform' task for the EPubMaker worker, but I am getting an error

> uninitialized constant Chapter::EPubMaker

The reason that I want to perform the task from the after_save is that Chapter is a nested model in the books form, but I only want to generate a new epub when a chapter has saved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because I didn't have the right naming for the worker file. I should have used underscores.